# C# convert datetime difference vs SQL Server convert datetime

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

In SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @UTC BIGINT
SET @UTC = 1563527339733 
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, @UTC % 1000, DATEADD(SECOND, @UTC / 1000, '19700101'))
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),cast('2019-07-19 09:08:59.733' as datetime), 108) 'hh:mi:ss'
```

Result: `09:08:59`

But in C# or ASP.Net MVC:

```
 DateTime dtCheck = DateTimeHelper.ConvertMilisecondToDateTimeUTC(1563527339733);
 string test = dtCheck.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Result of test in C#: `09:09:00`

Function Convert

```
 public static DateTime ConvertMilisecondToDateTimeUTC(long milisecond)
    {
        var dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(Math.Round(milisecond / 1000d));
        return dt;
    }
```

How can change it to the same?

Comment: Are you looking for `dtCheck.ToString("HH:mm:ss")` ?

Comment: @ Arulkumar: I want 090859 in C#, you can see, In c# it automatic round datetime

Comment: `ConvertMilisecondToDateTimeUTC` is your customized function, you can share what code is inside that.

Comment: I've been add function, you can see more detail.

Comment: In recent versions of the Framework, `DateTimeOffset` has a built-in `FromUnixTimeMilliseconds` method, so your conversion can be replaced with `DateTimeInfo.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(...).DateTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `Math.Round()` in the `ConvertMilisecondToDateTimeUTC()` function, will return your expected result.

```
public static DateTime ConvertMilisecondToDateTimeUTC(long milisecond)
{
    var dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(milisecond / 1000d);
    return dt;
}
```

Please find the [working demo](https://rextester.com/QUJW58619)